# Accessing each Item in an ASP ListView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to make the odd numbers `float:left` and the even `float:right`. However, apparently each item is odd AND element 1 no matter how many items are in the list. How can I access this in CSS. Obviously, since each item is `1` then the `:nth-child(odd) {float:left;}` and `:nth-child(even){float:right;}` does not work. How else can you access them?

It would be structured like so:

```
<div class="options">
                                <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="OptionsObjectDataSource" 
                                    EditIndex="-1" 
                                    OnPreRender="FabricsListView_PreRender">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="OptionsAltDropDownList" runat="server" style="width:100%"
                                            DataSourceID="OptionsObjectDataSource" 
                                            DataTextField="description" 
                                            DataValueField="id"
                                            AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                            OnDataBound="OptionsAltDropDownList_DataBound" >
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="">- Select Alt Option -</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="OptionsObjectDataSource" 
                                                runat="server" 
                                                SelectMethod="GetOptionList" 
                                                TypeName="Data.ProductList" > 
                                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:ListView>
                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="OtherObjectDataSource" runat="server"
                                                            SelectMethod="GetByProduct" 
                                                            TypeName="Data.RequirementList" 
                                                            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="OptionHiddenField" Name="id" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an AlternatingItemTemplate and adjust your CSS styles accordingly?

[Listview AlternatingItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.alternatingitemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you check the index. But you can use something like this:

```
<some_element style="<%#RenderItemStyle(Container.ItemIndex)%>"
```

Where "some_element" is whatever element inside your ItemTemplate. You would then create a function RenderItemStyle in your code behind class:

```
protected string RenderItemStyle(int index)
{
    if ((index % 2) == 0)
       return style_for_even_row;
    else
       return style_for_odd_row;
}
```

At runtime your RenderItemStyle will be called for every row. You can then do whatever you want inside your function based on "index" argument.

Answer (score 0):

It was the way I had my `div`s. They weren't in the proper place. I would elaborate, but I didn't post that piece in the code in my question. Basically, the ListView itself must be in a `div` (to encompass the entire List) and that `div` must also be inside a `div`, to give it some bounds. Furthermore, immediately inside the `<ItemTemplate>` must be a `div`. This is for each item in the list. That is the div for which child styles can now be properly applied.